# C++: different behaviour of overloading function and operator

Tags: c++

I'm new to and learning C++.
I have a question for function overload for classes.

I have two exactly same code below except the function name.
One is just a function and the other is operator.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class B;

class A {
  public:
    void test(A const &a) { cout << "AA" << endl; }
    void test(B const &b) { cout << "AB" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    void test(A const &a) { cout << "BA" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  B b1;
  B b2;
  b1.test(b2);
  return 0;
}
```

This program prints

```
BA
```

And here is another program.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class B;

class A {
  public:
    void operator=(A const &a) { cout << "AA" << endl; }
    void operator=(B const &b) { cout << "AB" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    void operator=(A const &a) { cout << "BA" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  B b1;
  B b2;
  b1.operator=(b2);
  return 0;
}
```

This program prints

```
AA
```

The only difference between these two programs is function name: test and operator=.
I don't understand why C++ behaves like this.
Is there anything I'm missing?

I'm compling this program with g++ version of 4.2.1 under mac OS X 8.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your first case, it is not about `overloading`, those two `test` functions in `A` are overloading, however, `test` in `B` and `A` is `name hiding` since `B` redefines `test`. `overloading` deals with function in same scope with `name hiding` is talking about class hierarchy.

So in the first case

```
b1.test(b2);
```

`b2` is an object of `B`, the `test` function in `B` expects const reference of class `A`, which is OK in this case, so it will output "BA".

In the second assignment operator case, you did not create an assignment operator to assign `B` into `B`, therefore the compiler created one for you. The one created by the compiler is calling assignment operator of `A`. Therefore, `AA` is printed.

If you add another `operator=` in B:

```
void operator=(B const &B) { cout << "BB" << endl; }
```

You will see "BB" printed out in your assignment operator case since in this case, compiler will not generate assignment operator for you.

Comment: execuse me but can i ask one more question? when i make all operator= virtual and make a pointer variable to A ptr and set to &b, (*ptr).operator=(c); would print "AB". It behaves like none of 2 cases above. Why does this happen?

Comment: @lbyeoksan virtual function is used to implement polymorphis, which means "one interface, multiple implementations". Since you assign b to base class A's pointer, it will first search class B whether you have defined the assignment operator for B, since you did not have it, it will search for base class's implementation and found the one with `const B&` as parameter, therefore, it will call that one.